# Prove if $M_{g_1}^A \cap M_{g_2}^A \neq 0 $ then $M_{g_1}^A = M_{g_2}^A $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ is a subgroup of $G$. Let define $M_g^A := \{ a * g | a \in A \}$ for an arbitrary element $g \in G$. How can i prove that, for any $g_1,g_2 \in G$, if $M_{g_1}^A \cap M_{g_2}^A \neq 0 $ then $M_{g_1}^A  = M_{g_2}^A  $

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $a_1g_1=a_2g_2, a_1,a_2\in A$, this implies that for every $a\in A$, $ag_1=a(a^{-1}_1a_1g)=(aa_1^{-1}a_2)g_2$ since $A$ is a group,$aa_1^{-1}a_2)\in A$ and $(aa_1^{-1}a_2))g_2\in M^A_{g_2}$, we deduce that $M^A_{g_1}\subset M^A_{g_2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $h \in M_{g_1}^A \cap M_{g_2}^A$. Then $h = a_1g_1 = a_2g_2$ for some $a_1,a_2 \in A$. Let $a * g_1 \in M_{g_1}^A$ be arbitrary. Then
$$a*g_1 = a*a_1^{-1}*a_1*g_1 = a*a_1^{-1}*h = a*a_1^{-1}*a_2*g_2 \in M_{g_2}^A,$$
since $a*a_1^{-1}*a_2 \in A$. So $M_{g_1}^A \subset M_{g_2}^A$, and by symmetry the reverse inclusion holds.

Answer (score 0):

Right cosets of a subgroup $A \subset G$ form a partition of $G$. Hence it gives an equivalence relation on the underlying set of $G$. Thus two distinct right cosets cannot have no-trivia intersection.